# Attaching electronics to a very bad chassis

Tags: chassis

I had a misfortune to buy this very poorly made tracked [chassis](https://usa.banggood.com/3V-7V-Light-Shock-Absorbed-Smart-Robot-Tank-Chassis-Car-DIY-Kit-With-130-Motor-p-1155263.html).

I now have some Arduino-based controller to attach to it. I see three posts with what seems to be holes for screws, and two of them even appear level :). Nothig I find on the internet matches the layout. In fact, there is no documentation on that chassis that would describe the layout.

Is there some generic part I could customize to cover this situation? Any tips and tricks for attaching PCBs to chassis would be appreciated.

Comment: get a sheet of cardboard and scissors ... breakfast cereal box cardboard would be easiest to cut ... make the sheet fit nicely ...then trace the sheet to aluminum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use a chassis so poorly made, its manufacturer has pushed you out of the realm of engineering and into tinkering.

I would suggest that you release yourself from the desire for precision, elegance, and beauty. Instead, embrace the embarrassment of cardboard, foamcore, X-acto knives, hot glue, and toothpicks.

Especially when it's necessary, such tinkering can actually be freeing. Commenter jsotola might agree.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I embraced my inner Tinkerer as @r-bryan and @jsotola suggested. Index cards and sewing needles and toothpicks and a digital caliper. Also QCad :) .

For any unfortunate who got stuck with the "3V-7V Light Shock Absorbed Smart Robot Tank Chassis Car DIY Kit With 130 Motor" (I place the full thing here advisedly to make it findable), here is the [cad file](https://github.com/belousa/tank-chassis) that got me there. Print it, tape to the rectangle of a plastic of your choice, drill the holes as indicated. Your plastic will fit. The thick column that goes through the plastic will need a spacer of ~2.5 mm under it, I am yet not done with that part. But the holes fit, as tested by the two toothpicks.